# ExecuteReader return null value for one of the column but data exist in the database

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

The ExecuteReader is returning a null value for the column MESSAGE in the code query  but the other columns are returning the right value. The data exist in the database as shown by the image below Please can anyone tell where I am going wrong

Oracle Database return

[image]

Oracle Create Table

```
 CREATE TABLE "CHT"."HEALTH_RECORD_MESSAGES" 
 (  
   "RECORD" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "MESSAGE" LONG, 
   "CREATED" DATE, 
    "CREATED_TIME" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "WHO_ENTERED" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "EXPIRES" DATE
```

)

Class Model

```
public class HealthRecordMessage
{
    public int RECORD { get; set; }
    public string MESSAGE { get; set; }
    public DateTime CREATED { get; set; }
    public DateTime CREATED_TIME { get; set; }
    public string WHO_ENTERED { get; set; }
}
```

C# Code

```
    public ActionResult SearchHealthRecordMessage(int? id)
    {
        List<HealthRecordMessage> HealthRecordMessage = new List<HealthRecordMessage>();
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HealthRecord"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT RECORD,MESSAGE,WHO_ENTERED,CREATED,CREATED_TIME
                                        FROM
                                            HEALTH_RECORD_MESSAGES

                                            Where  RECORD=:RecordId";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                
            cmd.Parameters.Add("RecordId", id);
            OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {                   
                var healthrecordMessage = new HealthRecordMessage();
                healthrecordMessage.RECORD =Convert.ToInt32(rdr["RECORD"]);
                healthrecordMessage.MESSAGE =rdr["MESSAGE"].ToString();// this is My problem  Message Value is null
                healthrecordMessage.WHO_ENTERED = rdr["WHO_ENTERED"].ToString();
                healthrecordMessage.CREATED = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["CREATED"]);
                healthrecordMessage.CREATED_TIME = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["CREATED_TIME"]);
                HealthRecordMessage.Add(healthrecordMessage);
            }
            //return View(patientList);
        }

        return Json(new { data = HealthRecordMessage }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line of code with `Add`. Run to the breakpoint, then go to the `Immediate Window` and type in `?healthrecordMessage.MESSAGE.Length` Please share the result of that.

Comment: What is the encoding of the field in the database?

Comment: @mjwills return from request   'healthrecordMessage.MESSAGE.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147467261
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    Source: "cd938a7e322d4459bb721016f0afcd9f"
    StackTrace: "   at <>x.<>m0(HealthRecordController <>4__this, Nullable`1 id)"
    TargetSite: {Int32 <>m0(NSCHT.HealthRecord.Controllers.HealthRecordController, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])}

Answer (score 0):

With help from  @mjwills  needed to add

```
cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1;
```